# Parsing an ini file

Tags: c, parsing

I have written a basic ini file parser in C. It won't support big ini files, and isn't very fast when fetching configuration values, but should be enough for small ones.

I couldn't find "proper" definition of ini file standard, so there is no handling screening symbols, and all and any error encountered during parsing is silently swallowed.

**inifile.h**

```
/** \file inifile.h
 * Functions for reading configuration from disk
 * Configuration options have single lines
 * Comments start with ';'
 */

#ifndef _INIFILE_H_
#define _INIFILE_H_

typedef void* pinifile_data;

/** Open and parse an ini file
 * \param[in] fname name of file to read
 * \param[out] pinidb pointer to the variable for storing reference for
 * inifile data
 * \returns 0 on success
 */
int open_ini_file(const char* fname, pinifile_data* pinidb);

int get_integer(const pinifile_data inidb, const char* section, const char* entry, int default_value);
double get_real(const pinifile_data inidb, const char* section, const char* entry, double default_value);

/** Free memory used by ini file database
 * \param[in] inidb ini file database from open_ini_file
 */
void close_ini_file(pinifile_data inidb);

/** Create ini file database */
pinifile_data create_inidb();

/** Add or change value in ini file database
 * If there is no specified section or entry in database, they will be created
 * \param inidb ini file database
 * \param[in] section name of a section
 * \param[in] entry name of an entry
 * \param[in] value new value of entry in string form
 */
void set_entry(pinifile_data inidb, const char* section, const char* entry, const char* value);

/** Dump ini file database on disc
 * \param fname name of a file to dump into
 * \param inidb ini file database
 * \returns 0 on success
 */
int dump_ini_file(const char* fname, pinifile_data inidb);

#endif // _INIFILE_H_
```

**inifile.c**

```
#include "inifile.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct inifile_entry
{
    const char* entry_name;
    const char* entry_value;
    struct inifile_entry* next_entry;
};

struct inifile_section
{
    const char* section_name;
    struct inifile_entry* first_entry;
    struct inifile_section* next_section;
};

struct inifile_data
{
    struct inifile_section* first_section;
};

void close_ini_file(pinifile_data inidb)
{
    struct inifile_data* pinidb = (struct inifile_data*)inidb;
    if(pinidb == NULL)
        return;

    struct inifile_section* pnext_s = NULL, * pcur_s = NULL;
    struct inifile_entry* pnext_e = NULL, * pcur_e = NULL;

    pcur_s = pinidb->first_section;
    while(pcur_s != NULL)
    {
        pnext_s = pcur_s->next_section;

        pcur_e = pcur_s->first_entry;
        while(pcur_e != NULL)
        {
            pnext_e = pcur_e->next_entry;
            if(pcur_e->entry_name != NULL)
                free((void*)pcur_e->entry_name);
            if(pcur_e->entry_value != NULL)
                free((void*)pcur_e->entry_value);
            free((void*)pcur_e);
            pcur_e = pnext_e;
        }
        if(pcur_s->section_name != NULL)
            free((void*)pcur_s->section_name); 
        free((void*)pcur_s);
        pcur_s = pnext_s;
    }
    free((void*)pinidb);
}

void init_section(struct inifile_section* psection)
{
    psection->section_name = NULL;
    psection->first_entry = NULL;
    psection->next_section = NULL;
}

void init_entry(struct inifile_entry* pentry)
{
    pentry->entry_name = NULL;
    pentry->entry_value = NULL;
    pentry->next_entry = NULL;
}

enum parser_states
{
    comment = 0,
    linestart,
    sectionentry,
    entryname,
    entryvalue,
    states_number
};

struct parser_state
{
    struct inifile_data context;
    struct inifile_section* section_cursor;
    struct inifile_entry* entry_cursor;
    char buffer[255];
    int buffer_cursor;
};

typedef enum parser_states (*ini_file_state_transition)(char next_char, struct parser_state* pastate);

enum parser_states comment_state(char next_char, struct parser_state* pastate)
{
    if(next_char == '\n')
    {
        pastate->buffer_cursor = 0;
    return linestart;
    }
    return comment;
}

enum parser_states linestart_state(char next_char, struct parser_state* pastate)
{
    if(next_char == '\n')
    {
        pastate->buffer_cursor = 0;
    return linestart;
    }
    if(next_char == ';')
    {
        pastate->buffer_cursor = 0;
        return comment;
    }
    if(next_char == ']' || next_char == '=')
    {
        // this is error, discard the string
        pastate->buffer_cursor = 0;
        return comment;
    }
    if(isspace(next_char))
        return linestart;
    if(next_char == '[')
    {
        pastate->buffer_cursor = 0;
    return sectionentry;
    }
    // in all other cases, start of entry
    if(pastate->section_cursor == NULL)
    {
        //entries without section are not considered
        pastate->buffer_cursor = 0;
    return comment;
    }
    pastate->buffer[pastate->buffer_cursor++] = next_char;
    return entryname;    
}

enum parser_states sectionentry_state(char next_char, struct parser_state* pastate)
{
    if(next_char == '\n')
    {
        // this is an error; data are discarded
        pastate->buffer_cursor = 0;
    return linestart;
    }
    if(next_char == '[' || next_char == ';')
        return comment;

    if(next_char != ']')
        pastate->buffer[pastate->buffer_cursor++] = next_char;
    // protection from buffer overflow
    if(next_char == ']' || pastate->buffer_cursor > 254)
    {
        // this is section name's end
    // if we have non-empty name, create new section
    if(pastate->buffer_cursor > 0)
    {
            // prepare next section
            if(pastate->section_cursor == NULL)
            {
                // make first section
                pastate->context.first_section = (struct inifile_section*)malloc(sizeof(struct inifile_section));
                init_section(pastate->context.first_section);
                pastate->section_cursor = pastate->context.first_section;
            }
            else
            {
                pastate->section_cursor->next_section = (struct inifile_section*)malloc(sizeof(struct inifile_section));
                init_section(pastate->section_cursor->next_section);
                pastate->section_cursor = pastate->section_cursor->next_section;
            }
            pastate->entry_cursor = NULL;
        pastate->section_cursor->section_name = (char*)malloc(pastate->buffer_cursor + 1);
        memcpy((void*)pastate->section_cursor->section_name, pastate->buffer, pastate->buffer_cursor);
        *(char*)(pastate->section_cursor->section_name + pastate->buffer_cursor) = '\0';
    }
    // discard the rest of the string
    return comment;
    }

    return sectionentry;

}

enum parser_states entryname_state(char next_char, struct parser_state* pastate)
{
    if(next_char == '\n')
    {
        // this is an error; data are discarded
        pastate->buffer_cursor = 0;
    return linestart;
    }
    if(next_char == ';' || next_char == '[' || next_char == ']')
    {
        // this is an error; data are discarded
        pastate->buffer_cursor = 0;
    return comment;
    }
    if(next_char != '=')
        pastate->buffer[pastate->buffer_cursor++] = next_char;
    // protection from buffer overflow
    if(pastate->buffer_cursor > 254)
    {
        // too long, discard everything
        pastate->buffer_cursor = 0;
    return comment;
    }

    if(next_char == '=')
    {
        // make new entry
        if(pastate->entry_cursor == NULL)
        {
            // make first entry
            pastate->section_cursor->first_entry = (struct inifile_entry*)malloc(sizeof(struct inifile_entry));
            init_entry(pastate->section_cursor->first_entry);
            pastate->entry_cursor = pastate->section_cursor->first_entry;
        }
        else
        {
            pastate->entry_cursor->next_entry = (struct inifile_entry*)malloc(sizeof(struct inifile_entry));
            init_entry(pastate->entry_cursor->next_entry);
        pastate->entry_cursor = pastate->entry_cursor->next_entry;
        }
        pastate->entry_cursor->entry_name = (char*)malloc(pastate->buffer_cursor + 1);
        memcpy((void*)pastate->entry_cursor->entry_name, pastate->buffer, pastate->buffer_cursor);
        *(char*)(pastate->entry_cursor->entry_name + pastate->buffer_cursor) = '\0';
        pastate->buffer_cursor = 0;
    return entryvalue;
    }
    return entryname;
}

enum parser_states entryvalue_state(char next_char, struct parser_state* pastate)
{
    enum parser_states res = entryvalue;
    if(next_char == '\n')
    {
        res = linestart;
    }
    else if(next_char == ';')
    {
        res = comment;
    }
    else
    {
        pastate->buffer[pastate->buffer_cursor++] = next_char;
    if(pastate->buffer_cursor > 254)
        res = comment;
    }
    if(res != entryvalue)
    {
        pastate->entry_cursor->entry_value = (char*)malloc(pastate->buffer_cursor + 1);
        memcpy((void*)pastate->entry_cursor->entry_value, pastate->buffer, pastate->buffer_cursor);
        *(char*)(pastate->entry_cursor->entry_value + pastate->buffer_cursor) = '\0';
        pastate->buffer_cursor = 0;
    }

    return res;

}

int open_ini_file(const char* fname, pinifile_data* pinidb)
{
    if(fname == NULL || pinidb == NULL)
        return 2;

    FILE* fstream = fopen(fname, "r");
    if(!fstream)
        return 1;

    struct parser_state context;
    memset(&context, 0, sizeof(struct parser_state));
    int character = 0, state_index = linestart;
    ini_file_state_transition parse_functions_table[] = {
        comment_state,
    linestart_state,
    sectionentry_state,
    entryname_state,
    entryvalue_state
    };
    do
    {
        character = fgetc(fstream);
    if(character != EOF)
    {
        state_index = parse_functions_table[state_index](character, &context);
    }
    } while(!(feof(fstream) || ferror(fstream)));
    fclose(fstream);

    *pinidb = malloc(sizeof(struct inifile_data));
    // here we are copying a pointer, yes
    memcpy(*pinidb, &context.context, sizeof(struct inifile_data));

    return 0;    
}

const char* get_value(const pinifile_data inidb, const char* section, const char* entry)
{
    struct inifile_data* pinidb = (struct inifile_data*)inidb;
    if(pinidb == NULL || section == NULL || entry == NULL)
        return NULL;

    struct inifile_section* pcur_s = NULL;
    struct inifile_entry* pcur_e = NULL;

    pcur_s = pinidb->first_section;
    while(pcur_s != NULL)
    {
        pcur_e = pcur_s->first_entry;

    if(!strcmp(section, pcur_s->section_name))
            while(pcur_e != NULL)
            {
                if(!strcmp(entry, pcur_e->entry_name))
                    return pcur_e->entry_value;
                pcur_e = pcur_e->next_entry;
            }
        pcur_s = pcur_s->next_section;
    }
    return NULL;

}

int get_integer(const pinifile_data inidb, const char* section, const char* entry, int default_value)
{
    const char* evalue = get_value(inidb, section, entry);
    if(!evalue)
        return default_value;
    return strtol(evalue, NULL, 10);
}

double get_real(const pinifile_data inidb, const char* section, const char* entry, double default_value)
{
    const char* evalue = get_value(inidb, section, entry);
    if(!evalue)
        return default_value;
    return strtod(evalue, NULL);

}

pinifile_data create_inidb()
{
    void* result = malloc(sizeof(struct inifile_data));
    memset(result, 0, sizeof(struct inifile_data));
    // Here we are copying a pointer, yes
    return result;
}

void set_entry(pinifile_data inidb, const char* section, const char* entry, const char* value)
{
    struct inifile_data* pinidb = (struct inifile_data*)inidb;
    if(pinidb == NULL || section == NULL || entry == NULL || value == NULL)
        return;

    struct inifile_section* target_section = NULL,* section_cursor = NULL;

    section_cursor = pinidb->first_section;
    while(section_cursor != NULL)
    {
        if(!strcmp(section, section_cursor->section_name))
    {
        target_section = section_cursor;
        break;
    }
    if(NULL == section_cursor->next_section)
        break;
        section_cursor = section_cursor->next_section;
    }
    if(target_section == NULL)
    {
         // prepare next section
         if(section_cursor == NULL)
         {
             // make first section
             pinidb->first_section = (struct inifile_section*)malloc(sizeof(struct inifile_section));
             init_section(pinidb->first_section);
             target_section = pinidb->first_section;
         }
         else
         {
             section_cursor->next_section = (struct inifile_section*)malloc(sizeof(struct inifile_section));
             init_section(section_cursor->next_section);
             target_section = section_cursor->next_section;
         }
         char* sname = (char*)malloc(strlen(section) + 1);
         target_section->section_name = strcpy(sname, section);
    }

    struct inifile_entry* target_entry = NULL,* entry_cursor = NULL;
    entry_cursor = target_section->first_entry;
    if(entry_cursor != NULL)
    {
        for(; entry_cursor->next_entry != NULL; entry_cursor = entry_cursor->next_entry)
        if(!strcmp(entry, entry_cursor->entry_name))
        {
            target_entry = entry_cursor;
        break;
        }
    }
    if(target_entry == NULL)
    {
        // prepare next entry
        if(entry_cursor == NULL)
        {
            // make first entry
            target_section->first_entry = (struct inifile_entry*)malloc(sizeof(struct inifile_entry));
            init_entry(target_section->first_entry);
            target_entry = target_section->first_entry;
        }
        else
        {
            entry_cursor->next_entry = (struct inifile_entry*)malloc(sizeof(struct inifile_entry));
            init_entry(entry_cursor->next_entry);
            target_entry = entry_cursor->next_entry;
        }
        char* ename = (char*)malloc(strlen(entry) + 1);
        target_entry->entry_name = strcpy(ename, entry);
    }
    if(target_entry->entry_value != NULL)
        free((void*)target_entry->entry_value);

    char* eval = (char*)malloc(strlen(value) + 1);
    target_entry->entry_value = strcpy(eval, value);
}

int dump_ini_file(const char* fname, pinifile_data inidb)
{
    struct inifile_data* pinidb = (struct inifile_data*)inidb;
    if(fname == NULL || pinidb == NULL)
        return 1;
    FILE* fstream = fopen(fname, "w");
    if(!fstream)
        return 1;

    struct inifile_section* section_cursor = pinidb->first_section;
    while(section_cursor != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(fstream, "[%s]\n", section_cursor->section_name);
    struct inifile_entry* entry_cursor = section_cursor->first_entry;
    while(entry_cursor != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(fstream, "%s=%s\n", entry_cursor->entry_name, entry_cursor->entry_value);
        entry_cursor = entry_cursor->next_entry;
    }
        section_cursor = section_cursor->next_section;
    }
    fclose(fstream);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file

Comment: Not sure why are you bringing this up

Comment: @Srv19 because the article mentions that "The INI file format is not well defined", so you most probably won't find a definitive INI standard, as you already wrote. Thus you should also document what kind of files your parser accepts, that too helps with the review part.

Comment: It is preferable to post another question with the updated code, if you're interested in a follow-up. Code should not be edited after receiving answers, to avoid creating out of context reviews. Please take a moment to read: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a quick look, there are a few things I see that can be improved:

- Your code has a lot of unnecessary type casts. In special, casting to `void*` is not just useless, but also dangerous, since it might hide an error like passing a value to a function that expects a pointer. Never explicitly cast to `void*` when you call `free`, `memcpy`, etc.
- Casting from `void*` to `T*` is also unnecessary in C. `void*` converts implicitly both ways. Unless you really care about having the same code compile as C and C++, no need to cast in places like the return value from `malloc`.
- You can save type-name repetition in places like this:

  > ```
  > pinifile_data create_inidb()
  > {
  >     void* result = malloc(sizeof(struct inifile_data));
  >     memset(result, 0, sizeof(struct inifile_data));
  >     // Here we are copying a pointer, yes
  >     return result;
  > }
  > ```

  By instead using the variable name in the `sizeof` expression. `sizeof` is compile-time, so it is legal. E.g.:

  ```
  pinifile_data create_inidb(void)
  {
      struct inifile_data* result = malloc(sizeof(*result));
      memset(result, 0, sizeof(*result));
      return result;
  }
  ```

  Take advantage of the little type inference you have and **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself. If you change the name of that type, now it's just one place to update in that function.

  But going further, since that function wants to allocate zero-initialized memory, why not use [`calloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/) instead?

  ```
  pinifile_data create_inidb(void)
  {
      return calloc(1, sizeof(struct inifile_data));
  }
  ```
- I personally find impractical prefixing every instantiation of a structure with `struct`, so I always typedef them on declaration to avoid that. Same for `enum`s.
- You have a few formatting issues in your code, which hurt readability. A tool like [Clang Format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) can automate fixing that.
- Adding curly braces `{ }` on single line statements is optional, but a good idea. It will make future updates to your code less painful and less error prone.

Answer (score 2):

The `set_entry` function is too large. Refactor it to several ones.

Section, entry, value can't be `NULL`, so it's better to use const reference.

`open_ini_file` returns `1,2,0` What do they mean? Use human readable defines or enumeration.

Comment: Const reference is a C++ thing, this is plain C, so no other option but pointer.